# Check for pattern in logstash fieldName

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash

I have the following object structure. The number of comments is not fixed

```
comment1 {},
comment2 {}
...
```

How do I check for if number exists in fieldName in the filter plugin, something like

```
if [fieldname] contains numbers then do something
```

Comment: You would have to use a ruby filter to iterate over the contents of the event.

Comment: Hey @Badger do you have an example I can take a look at?

Comment: I do have ruby filter that I am using to spilt the comment array into their own fields, what I want to do now is if the field is having comment1/comment2, I want to extract it in a separate index.  ruby {
         code => "
           i = 1
           event.get('comments').each {|comment|
           event.set('comment'+i.to_s,comment)
           i += 1
        }"
    }

Comment: Just an idea, not the best solution i guess, but when i had a similar thing where i had snmptraps coming into logstash which were not defeined to a fixed length i just took them in, did a basic pipeline on it just to get what i needed and used the exec output towards a python script that did all it's magic and then sent it to another pipeline to save it into elastic, having an unknown number of events was one of the reasons i had to do it, the other part was that ruby was not able to hexlify properly